# Как при клике на кнопку открыть новую страницу?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, знаю вопрос простой, но всё таки, как при клике на кнопку открыть новую страницу, это нужно сделать при помощи JS
У меня 2 страницы в проекте и при нажатии на кнопку в одной из них должна открыться вторая

Comment: `window.location = '...'`

Comment: Вы бы код прикрепили, а кнопку `button` можно элементарно сделать ссылкой `<a href=""></a>` и не нужен тут `js`

Comment: А как сделать чтобы он открывал ссылку через некоторое время (с задержкой), например через 2 секунды?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `window.open(url);`
- `location = url;`
- etc

```js
document.getElementById('first-button')
  .addEventListener('click', () => window.open('https://w3.org'));

document.getElementById('second-button')
  .addEventListener('click', () => location = 'https://w3.org');
```

```html
<button id="first-button">Click me!</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="second-button">Click me!</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eop1umxn

Comment: Как-то нелогично.. для `open` `window.` написали, а для `location` нет))

Comment: @entithat, я как-то даже и не обращал внимания и не знал, что `open()` и без `window` работать будет — так видно у меня  исторически сложилось :)